# Mark Unmark grid record dirty

Tags: extjs, grid, store, extjs4.1

We are providing an ability to the user to change the order/position of a grid record. For this we are using drag and drop. But after drag and drop the record doesn't appear dirty.

Thus, is there any function which can be used to forcefully mark as well as unmark a grid record as dirty? That is, forcing it to display/hide the red mark in corner.

I found a function - `setDirty()` on the record. But this doesn't serve the purpose.

Comment: Does your model include the `index` property? I believe it is the property that changes when you reorder things, and if defined in the model the model record should become dirty upon drag-drop (works for trees anyway).

Comment: I think you should set a listener to your `DragDrop` plugin on `drop` Event and there you can process all the order-related changes (send new position to server and so on).

Comment: @Izhaki: There is an index in the store, but index in model I have not heard of. Could you please elaborate a bit more at what you are mentioning?

Comment: @webbandit: Thanks for the post. We are able to take care of the server side updation, but the issue is that how should a user gets to know that he has changed the order of some record? If that record gets marked dirty then its easier for the user to identify that the record order has been changed. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Just add a field `{name: 'index', type: 'int'}` to your model - it might do the trick. By defining it, ExtJS will monitor changes to it and will mark any record as dirty when you re-order your records (again, this is how trees work, which I assume is the same for grids).

Comment: Thanks for sharing this idea @Izhaki. Unfortunately its not working in case of grid. Any other workaround?

Comment: Could you please provide a code snippet of how the drag-drop functionality?

Comment: Why does `setDirty()` method doesnt's serve your purpose?

Comment: @webbandit: I evaluated things further and found that setDirty() marks a record dirty and displays a red flag only in the case when any of the displayed column in the record gets modified, otherwise, it doesn't display any such thing. As order is not getting managed internally due to which setDirty doesn't mark the record as dirty.

Comment: @Izhaki: Thanks Izhaki, have been able to find out a workaround for this.

Answer (score 1):

I've done a sequencing drag and drop grid before. I had a sequence column on the database and so simply included it in my model definition.

Then in the *gridview's* `drop` event handler, I called `record.set('sequence', newSequence)` on all effected records whenever a drop was performed. (I say "all effected records" because whenever you change the sequence of one record it doesn't only effect the sequence of that one record e.g.: if you move a record from the very bottom of the grid to the very top *all* of record sequence numbers after the dropped record will be increased by one, they will all be dirty and need to be updated on the database).

Using `record.set` will then show that the record's sequence column is dirty with a flag.

You said that you have the server side updating ok so I am assuming that you are performing this resequencing logic on the server side, you would have to move it back onto the JS, I don't know if you want to do that.

Comment: Thanks Geronimo. This is exactly what we had been doing too. But thought, there could be some other better method of doing this. Looks like, we have to keep using the same logic of old and new order. Thanks for the time though.